# Is it possible to do a certain task when a user clicks on a push notification?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I want to implement push notifications in an iOS and Android Phonegap app.

The question is: is it possible to do a certain task when clicking on a push notification?

I found there is a Phonegap plugin (PushPlugin) https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin but I couldn't find if it's possible to do some actions when the users clicks at a notification. For example open the correct view.

If it is possible, could someone provide an example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in android you can start a service by binding it, and then it will stopped automatically after completing the task in onBind() Method. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more on services. Or alternatively you can use [Intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to open appropriate interface/activity.

Comment: So beside push messages I also have to implement a service to get this work?

Comment: if your task doesn't needed user interaction, use service because service works in background and have no interface to show on screen otherwise create an activity and use intent filters to open that particular activity.

Comment: You can open specific activity on click of Notification.